# Google Sheets Scripts Number Decimal Place Fomatting

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets Script Editor, I am trying to create a custom function that can help me format a number string with a certain amount of decimal places. I need the string to be a number type so that the data can be charted.

The reason I need this function is because I have a in-cell dropdown that triggers the displays different sets of numbers with different decimal places within a cell. Therefore, I cannot rely on the static number formatting settings within Sheets.

While this returns the number of decimal places I want...

```
function format(amt) { return amt.toFixed(2); }
```

toFixed() creates a text string, therefore the value cannot be used for charting (the chart will say "No Data").

I have tried the following alternatives...

```
return parseFloat(amt); // var = number; can chart but cannot control decimal places
return parseFloat(amt).toFixed(2); //var = string; cannot chart
return parseInt(amt).toFixed(2); //var = string; cannot chart
```

Can anyone let me know if there is a way to create a custom function that lets me control the number of decimal places I want while keepign it as a number string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function format(x, n){
    x = parseFloat(x);
    n = n || 2;
    return parseFloat(x.toFixed(n))
}
```

Basically you need to parse the value after the toFixed() method is called, but you're parsing it before the toFixed() method is called.

With the above function you can say `format(amt)` to get 2 decimal places, or `format(2, n)` to get `n` decimal places

Comment: Thank you! I just tested this out and this works most of the time. If x = 0.30, it will get displayed as 0.3, instead of 0.30. Is there anyway to keep trailing zeros for "n"?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible without converting it back to a string

Comment: Looks like I must create a hidden column simply to store the numbers and display the strings on the visible column. Thank you for your help once again!

Comment: sure thing! if I helped please upvote and accept my answer I appreciate it

Comment: Recommend this slight change to the function: `x = parseFloat(x.replace(/,/g, ''));` which will help handle API / JSON returns with pretty formatting.